# What is this interesting syntax error? Mayavi mlab using in Anaconda-spyder

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder, biopython, mayavi

There is an interesting SyntaxError when I called "mayavi mlab lib".
Here is a part of my code:

```
from mayavi import mlab 
fig=mlab.figure(size=(1280,720))
#mlab.figure(1,bgcolor=(0,0,0))
mlab.clf()
pts = mlab.points3d(x,y,z, 1.5 * scalars.max()-scalars, 
scale_factor=0.015,resolution=10)
pts.mlab_source.dataset.lines=np.array(connection)
tube=mlab.pipeline.tube(pts,tube_radius=0.15)
tube.filter.radius_factor=1.
tube.filter.vary_radius='vary_radius_by_scalar'
mlab.pipeline.surface(tube,color=(0.8,0.8,0))

mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.gaussian_splatter(pts))
mlab.view(49,31.5,52.8,(4.2,37.3,20.6))
mlab.show()
```

and Error

> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\apptools\persistence\state_pickler.py", line 1210

```
^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

SyntaxError ss is here:

[image: SyntaxError position]

Thank in advance.

Note:Windows 10, Anaconda-Spyder, python 2.7 and 3.7 I using both of them, I installed mayavi and vtk etc. what it needed via anaconda command prompt.

Comment: Do you know why there are a bazillion extra blank lines in the installed library file you have open in your IDE? Did you put those there? They're causing your problem.

Comment: Uninstall, reinstall, and try not to do whatever caused all those blank lines.

Comment: No I did nothing, I delete extra lines but nothing changed. I don't know why.

Comment: I'm gonna reinstall this program.

Comment: I'm having the same issue: just installed mayavi (`conda.exe install mayavi`) and said file (`apptools\persistence\state_pickler.py`) contains all those empty lines. Win10 64bit, python3.7.4, conda 4.7.12, mayavi-4.6.2. See also [github issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11328)

Comment: I'm reinstalled Anaconda and python(this time version 3.5) and I tried to delete empty lines, and it's worked. I guess this error is caused by the program or some bugs.